# Famous symbols in Physics

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask this question here. I'll delete it if it's not.

My roommate is graduating and I want to DIY a wood bookmark with his name and some physical stuff on it(he's studying high energy physics), like simple pictures illustrating beautiful physical ideas. For example, in math we use the following picture to prove Pythagorean Theorem in ancient China. [image].

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not a bad question, and nicely asked too (+1). Unfortunately that's borderline off-topic here, and humor towards such questions has been running low lately. You may have better luck searching the 'net for physics geek/nerdy artifacts for possible ideas.

Comment: Depending on the high energy physics he's doing, perhaps a Feynman diagram comes to mind?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=+symbols++Physics&tbm=isch https://www.google.com/search?q=diagram++Physics+&tbm=isch https://www.google.com/search?q=diagram++quantum&tbm=isch